# My regex doesn't recognize arabic character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to stop repeating of a character more than 3 times, to transform it to juste 3 times.

Example : aaaaaaaaaall  => aaall

So, I did it with english character, and it worked :

```
$patternReplace = '/(.)\1{3,}/i';
$chaine = preg_replace($patternReplace, "$1$1$1", $chaine, -1 );
```

but it doesnt work for arabic character, like :

```
أأأأأأأأأأأأأأأأأأأأأأأأأأأأ
```

thanx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `u` modifier:

```
$patternReplace = '/(.)\1{3,}/iu';
$chaine = preg_replace($patternReplace, "$1$1$1", $chaine, -1 );
```

Docs from [PHP.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> u (PCRE_UTF8)
>   This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern and the subject is checked since PHP 4.3.5. An invalid subject will cause the preg_* function to match nothing; an invalid pattern will trigger an error of level E_WARNING. Five and six octet UTF-8 sequences are regarded as invalid since PHP 5.3.4 (resp. PCRE 7.3 2007-08-28); formerly those have been regarded as valid UTF-8.

Comment: @user3134277 Happy it worked for you! To accept an answer you should press the tick below the arrows on the left of that answer :-)